# What is the difference between “Bises” and “Bisous” when ending a letter?

Tags: salutations, correspondance

I've [learned](http://de.bab.la/phrasen/persoenlich/brief/deutsch-franzoesisch/) that at the end of a letter to a friend it's appropriate to write `Bises, (name)` or `Bisous, (name)`. e.g. between two female friends writing each other

**What is the difference in the usage of “Bises” and “Bisous”?**

Is one of them more common or used more by children or in a very familial context?

Comment: There is no difference, really. Bisous is little kisses, and bises is kisses. In terms of ***translation***. Bisous is more afectionate.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Bises* usually means kisses on the cheeks and is the kind of closing you write to someone you precisely kiss that way in real life (family, close / female friends, female colleagues). This kind of kiss is usually quite formal and not real kisses. People just touch cheeks to each other and kiss the air a specific number of times, usually two but can be one, three of four depending on the region.

*Bisous* is more friendly and affectionate, and are real kisses where the lips touch the skin. *Bisous* is generally used when writing to children or between lovers.

There are many people for whom I might end a postcard with *Bises* or *Grosses bises* but who would be very surprised if I wrote instead *Bisous* or *Gros bisous*.

Comment: Thanks. This really helpful and exactly the kind of "getting a feeling" for the use of these terms I was looking for. :-)

Comment: Is it reserved only for lovers to say "bisou bisou" in a p2p text?
I am asking it here since otherwise would be labelled as a duplicate, I am afraid.

Comment: @Sathyam Not sure what exactly you mean with "p2p text". *Bisou bisou* (more often *bisous bisous*) is not reserved to lovers but imply some intimacy.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci, *p2p - Peer to Peer*.

Answer (score 6):

*Bisous* is for very close people like family / girlfriend...

Young french people say *la bise* to their friends at the end of their messages

I've never seen *Bises* without *la* in a message

Comment: Interesting. I _always_ see _bises_ sans _la_ :-)

Comment: I mostly use "Bises" without "la". To me, "La bise" is more slangy. Both "Bises" or "La bise" are fine anyway.