# Comment demander poliment à une femme

Tags: vocabulaire

Comment puis-je demander poliment à une femme "Can I kiss you?"

*Puis-je vous baiser ?* ou il me faut dire *Puis-je vous embrasser ?*

Je ne comprends pas le sens du verbe "baiser" :

- embrasser
- tromper, duper
- faire l'amour

Je ne voudrais pas que cette femme pense que je veux avoir des relations sexuelles avec elle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Baiser*, as a verb, means “fuck”. It's vulgar and refers to having sex, not to kissing. It also has some of the same figurative meanings as “fuck” in English, but not nearly as many, e.g. “*Je me suis fait baiser*” = “I got screwed” (i.e. a vulgar way of saying I was tricked). *Baiser* used to mean kiss, but in 20th/21st century French from France, this meaning has completely disappeared. I think this is the case in other varieties of French as well, but there may be exceptions. “*Puis-je vous baiser ?*” meant “may I kiss you” in French a few centuries ago, but today, it means “May I fuck you?”, except that it weirdly uses *vous* way past the level of familiarity where you should have switched to *tu*.

*Un baiser*, as a noun, means a kiss. It's not used much anymore, possibly due to the evolution of the verb. *Une bise* is the more common word.

*Embrasser* (which originally meant to hold in one's arm) is the main verb meaning “kiss”. It's mostly used in a somewhat intimate context: one *embrasse* one's family and one's date, but typically not one's friends. “*Puis-je vous embrasser ?*” is a technically correct way of asking “May I kiss you?”, but it's something you'd ask a date, not an acquaintance. And it's very weird because at this stage of intimacy, you should have switched to *tu* long ago.

***Faire la bise*** is the correct phrase to use for greeting someone by cheek kissing. If you meet a woman and you're unsure whether she prefers cheek kissing or some other form of greeting, a standard way to ask is “*On se fait la bise ?*”, or more formally “*Voulez-vous qu'on se fasse la bise ?*” or some variant. (Not “*Est-ce que je vous fait la bise ?*” because it's a mutual act.)

Comment: On a related note: is *bisous* an equivalent to *bise* or is it more a kind of word used mostly in a family or with small children?

Comment: @RogerVadim Good question! It's complicated. *Bisou* is often equivalent to *bise* and indeed mostly used with children. But it's also sometimes appropriate for a kiss between lovers even when *bise* wouldn't be. And it's more commonly pluralized (*bisous*) than *bise* is. I'd never realized how subtle those words are!

Comment: @RogerVadim See https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24812/what-is-the-difference-between-bises-and-bisous-when-ending-a-letter

Comment: Il y a aussi le  mot « _poutou_ », mais peu nombreuses sont les personnes à l'utiliser librement.

Comment: @LPH *Poutou* est surtout régional, et quasi-inconnu dans la moitié nord de la France.

Answer (score 3):

Quelques variations intéressantes:

- direct: On s'embrasse?
- impulsif: [J'ai envie de t'embrasser](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/SUk1mc0mgT0)
- interrogatif: Est-ce que je peux t'embrasser?
- précautionneux: Puis-je te (vous) voler un baiser?
- persévérant: [Un jour j'y arriverai, je t'embrasserai](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-8iJ-3meqas)
- hidalgo: [Viens m'embrasser?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKiR51WQB-M)
- indirect: [Embrasse-moi quand tu voudras](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cXRGdbcW2Y)
- gêné: Je voudrais t'embrasser... mais sans t'embarrasser
- plus dansant: [Donne-moi un baiser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHiSA3Hpn3A), [deux baisers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oENpXg1zoFk), trois petits baisers...
- moins connu: [Donne-moi un petit baiser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYssqbBezaI)
- plus rock: [Je voudrais te donner un baiser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CM7z42fn220)
- plus poétique: [Je chante un baiser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5weqdVaChQ)

A quoi la réponse espérée est

- [Embrasse-moi idiot!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frjgEVMHKsY)

Bien sûr le lieu choisi a son importance:

- [sur les bancs publics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMtFfPbcPLM)

Et il y a aussi [le baiser magique](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKmY-4sp1Lk)!

Comment: Bel exercice de style. ça marche aussi avec "monsieur, votre nez est grand!" ?

Comment: @Archemar, Rostand toujours: Un ruban [baise-moi-ma-mignonne](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Rostand_-_Cyrano_de_Bergerac.djvu/18), couleur [inventée par Agrippa d’Aubigné quatre siècles plus tôt](https://books.google.fr/books?id=yF7WmHcAxJAC&pg=PA20).

Answer (score 2):

*Puis-je t'embrasser / vous embrasser ?* sounds very formal for such a situation.

> Note d’usage : Aujourd’hui, cette form (puis-je) est seulement employée dans des phrases appartenant au **registre soutenu**, à la forme interrogative inversée, ou de concert avec la conjonction si. Dans la langue courante, on emploie plus volontiers la forme longue « Est-ce que je peux ? » ou la forme simple « Je peux ». https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/puis#fr-flex-verb.

*Est-ce que je peux t'embrasser / vous embrasser ?* or even *Je peux t'embrasser / vous embrasser ?* with rising intonation sound more suitable, at least to my no native ears.

Comment: Note that there's also a nuance between *embrasser* and *faire la bise* (see my answer). If you're using *vous* with someone, you're not intimate enough for *embrasser*.

Comment: +1 On dira même probablement "on peut s'embrasser?" qui est ambigu, à la fois une suggestion et une question polie. C'est la forme moderne de "pouvons-nous nous embrasser?" qui n'est pas vraiment désuet, mais à peine plus utilisé (à l'oral) que "puis-je" qui lui l'est totalement comme vous le soulignez. Il est amusant de voir le glissement d'embrasser... qui vient de bras, et voulait dire [prendre dans ses bras](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/embrasser).

Answer (score 0):

Uniquement « Puis-je vous embrasser  ? » convient en traduction  stricte de « Can I kiss you? » ; on peut aussi utiliser le nom « baiser » pour dire la même chose.

- Puis-je vous donner/faire un baiser ?  (*« faire » n'est pas très utilisé*)

Il y a cependant un problème : « donner » est utilisé pour les baisers sur les joues (par exemple) et sur la bouche ; on n'emploie pas « faire » pour les baisers sur la bouche. Pour les baisers sur les joues, les gens utilisent plutôt « bise », qui ne va pas du tout pour les baisers sur la bouche.

Note : S'il s'agit d'un long baiser il est toujours donné sur la bouche.

[image]

Faire attention à la première construction, elle est trompeuse.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/baiser)) **sens 2** (Intransitif) (Vulgaire) (Par euphémisme) Euphémisme de coïter, s’accoupler, copuler.
> Quand je baise, la peur que j'ai d'être enceinte me coupe toute envie de jouir. Je n'aime pas baiser. — (Pierre Louÿs, Trois filles de leur mère, René Bonnel, Paris, 1926, chapitre IV)
>
> **sens 3** (Transitif) Posséder, prendre, sexuellement.

C'est le sens « 3 » qui est utilisé dans la première question, et même si le dictionnaire considère que seulement le sens « 2 » est vulgaire, je ne crois pas que ce soit le cas ; la proximité du sens et de la forme  de ces deux termes est beaucoup trop grande pour que ce soit le cas ; personnellement je considère les deux comme également très vulgaires.

Pour un terme correct et sans ambiguïté à la place du vulgaire « baiser » il y a toujours l'euphémisme « coucher avec ».

As, apparently, you know English, you should refer to the same ambiguity that exists for the verb « to fuck » in English. The situation is similar in French for « baiser ». It would do you much good also, as you seem quite fluent in French, to go through the definitions of « baiser » in this dictionary : [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/baiser).

Comment: “*Donner un baiser*” is technically correct but very unusual. “*Faire un baiser*” is more common, but somewhat old-fashioned. “*Faire une bise*” or “*faire la bise*” is much more standard. For French kissing, neither *donner* nor *faire* are appropriate: one would use the verb *embrasser*. “*Bise*” is never used for French kissing. “*Baiser*” is sometimes, but it's typically used to refer to the act from an outside perspective (e.g. “my first kiss” = “*mon premier baiser*”) and not combined with a verb.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Il me semble que "bise" convient plutôt à des milieux olé olé, ou à des milieux pour qui la familiarité est innée.

Comment: En famille on pourra aussi utiliser *bisous* pour des baisers affectueux sur les joues.

Comment: Je n'écrirais pas ***Seulement** « Puis-je vous embrasser ? » convient[...]* mais ***Seul** « Puis-je vous embrasser ? » convient[...]*

Comment: @jlliagre Je me souviens que vous m'avez fait cette remarque déjà une fois, et j'avais alors tout simplement fait confiance à votre jugement ; cependant, j'y pense de nouveau maintenant, je ne comprends pas ; selon ce dont je dispose rien ne justifie que ce serait une erreur :  l'adverbe « seulement » signifie « b) À l'exclusion de tout autre chose ou de toute autre personne. Synon. exclusivement, uniquement. » ([TLFi, A 1. b))](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/seulement), et de plus « seul » n'est qu'un adjectif. Pourquoi l'adv. ne convient-il pas, et  quel est cet usage de « seul » ?

Comment: @LPH Je ne dis pas que c'est foncièrement incorrect mais que ce n'est pas ce que j'aurais choisi. En début de phrase, le sens de *seulement* est généralement **B.- 1.** *Souvent placé en tête de phrase ou de proposition, sert à marquer une restriction ou une opposition à ce qui vient d'être dit ou écrit*. Le sens de *seul* que je propose serait celui décrit en [**I.- C.- 1.**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/seul) : *[Dans des constr. attributives ou avec la fonction d'épith. mais avec une valeur adv.]* C'est le même genre de *seul* que celui de la phrase *Dieu seul le sait*.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci pour les précisions ; ma notion inexplicable que « seul » était parfois un advebe s'explique maintenant. Il s'agit donc de faire un choix qui élimine une indéfinition au départ.

Comment: @LPH Avec *uniquement*, tu as éliminé l'ambiguïté mais malheureusement pas la lourdeur. *Uniquement Dieu le sait* ??

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne perçoit pas la lourdeur ; il est vrai que cet adverb ne se trouve pas au début des phrases, mais il y a cet exemple qui montre que l'inversion parait naturelle : « Uniquement trois partis ont plus de dix (10) députés. Quatre partis seulement auront plus de dix (10) parlementaires. Sept (7) petits partis uniquement ont la possibilité de bénéficier d'un (1) à cinq (5) députés. ». Ne serait-ce pas plutôt une question d'usage inhabituel ?